# UIActivityViewController: how to exclude own share extension from the activity displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-sharesheet

My application has a share extension that allows the user to share photos with my application.
From within my application, the user can share photos with other applications.
When the user selects share from within my own application, how could I exclude my own share extension from the list of available applications to share with?

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue:"com.myapp.ShareImage")]
```

Tried with above method but no result.